# Is there a way to select an element only when two Selector true without javascript?

Tags: html, css

I need to know if, with CSS, you can use two selectors at the same time as an if condition.

For example, I would like to change color of a  element only when that  is :active at the same time as a sibling element is :hover.

Unfortunately I need to do it only with CSS, I hope it is possible.

Comment: What is your `HTML` structure?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it is entirely dependent on your HTML structure.

Comment: It might be possible but it depends on HTML structure.

Comment: I have no problem with the structure, because I'm doing it to practice, my idea was to change properties to a container only when clicked and dragged to another container, for example outside it. Obviously without using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More or less what you said, specifically if `<p>` is an `.inner`
>   sibling node, `.inner` should change only when it had `:active`
>   meanwhile you hovered on the `<p>` tag

`:active` is applied upon clicking so click the text

```css
.container {
  padding-top:30px;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.inner {
  width: 150px;
  height:70px;
  border:1px solid green;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}

.inner:active p:hover { 
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container active"> 
 <div class="inner">
  <p> I am some text, click me </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm trying to do. What I want is to have the chance to click an element and drag it onto another to make a change.

Comment: `For example, I would like to change color of a element only when that is :hover at the same time as another item is :active.`  I have provided a solution to that example and thus should be accepted as an answer. You haven't specified exactly what you want to do other than giving an example...It's not appropriate to say this isn't what you want given what I wrote above.

If you want an answer regarding draging elements to other places then put that in your original question.

Comment: Further more, if this is regarding dragging an element to another then this example would still work. E.G. take my answer above. If the `<p>` was outside of `.inner` and then it got dragged into the `.inner` div... it would still work.

Comment: Sorry if I made mistakes in making a question, I did't know how to explain it, I made some changes to make the idea better. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So in basic terms, you want to affect the parent element based on it's sibling element?

Comment: E.G. If in my example above, if `.inner` had `:active` and then if you hovered on the `<p>` tag, the `.inner` (parent element) should change?

Comment: More or less what you said, specifically if <p> is an .inner sibling node, .inner should change only when it had :active meanwhile you hovered on the <p> tag. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @RaffaeleVinci Ok I think I understand - check my answer again

Comment: Actually, not just yet.

Comment: @RaffaeleVinci I have just realised. How do you propose to have `:active` AND a `:hover` state at the same time? `:active` means currently clicked.. you can't click and hover at the same time ? You can do it with an `.active` class but other than that... I'm not sure how you get the two together at once?

Comment: Okay, that's what comes closest to what I'm trying to do. However, it seems to me that it is not possible to do the same thing without `<p>` being the `.inner` direct child. Is that right?

Comment: No, you can do it if `<p>` was a sibling of `.inner` by using the `+` CSS selector E.G. `.inner + p`

Comment: Perfect, that was what I was about what I was trying to do, thank you very much for the help

Comment: Glad you found the solution, happy coding! ^.^